# Ubuntu 20.04 for Mac not available

Tags: 20.04, arm64

A couple months ago I was successfully able to install Ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS desktop image for my 2020 M1 Mac. However upon looking for a reinstallation recently, I discovered that this version of the desktop image is not available on the Ubuntu website. Would this be the case or will I be able to find an active version of the desktop image of 20.04 for Mac somewhere?

Thank You.

Comment: You might be thinking of “Asahi Linux”, which is not Ubuntu 

Comment: Are you planning to use Ubuntu virtually? You can dual boot MacOS and Asahi Linux, which runs directly on the Mac (not just virtually), and it can utilize the computer's power more efficiently than virtually running Ubuntu could. It even supports the graphics card. https://asahilinux.org/2022/03/asahi-linux-alpha-release/ (support for hardware is gradually getting better).